# Detect Distance Between Elements on Scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using jQuery to change a fixed div at the top of the screen `top:0`.
When the scroll gets to a certain point the class is changed and CSS is changed. Great.

However, I was looking for a better way. Since I am changing it when it reaches 30px away from the content block, doing what I did below doesn't work well since it is using a fixed height:

```
$(function(){
  $(document).scroll(function() {
    var x = $(this).scrollTop();
    if(x > 2025) {
      if($(window).width() > 950) {                
        $('.topFullWidthWhite').addClass('nonStick');
      }
    } else {
      $('.topFullWidthWhite').removeClass('nonStick');
    }
  });
});
```

SO...

Is there a way of doing something more along the lines of...

```
if(x <= 20 from /* HTML ELEMENT */){
    //DO WHATEVER HERE
}
```

If there is a way of doing this relative to other elements rather than document height that would be grand.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try to make use of `offset().top` for that particular element after which you want to change the css

```js
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
  var two = $(".two").offset().top;
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > two - 20) {
    $(".two").addClass("reached");
  } else {
    $(".two").removeClass("reached");
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  margin-bottom: 400px;
}

.one {
  height: 150px;
  background: green;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.two {
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}

.two.reached {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
```